# Ability to track Notes & Attachments downloads on Shield Event Monitoring

Tags: shield, event-monitoring

The Shield event monitoring app provides us a dashboard to view downloads of Files in Salesforce. Our company also wants to track downloads of 'Notes & Attachments'. Is it possible to create a report/dashboard that can track 'Notes & Attachment' downloads?

I tried looking in to the 'Content Transfer Event Type' but the records in the dataset only have ID's of files listed and not notes & attachments.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_documentattach.htm